# How to make the side panel visible always in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

hi i have tried the following code,

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-theme="a">

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#slidingDialogs', function(){       
    $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open");
});
```

the panel is getting at first but clicking on that it is just hiding, but i need it to stay always, can someone help me please thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think adding following two property to false will do the trick.

- `data-dismissible = "false"`
- `data-swipe-close = "false"`

Try following code:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" data-swipe-close="false">
```

Comment: i have added as you gave but it is displaying nothing and when i saw in consaole iam having div as <div id="mypanel" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-reveal ui-panel-closed ui-body-a ui-panel-animate" data-swipe-close="false" data-dismissible="false" data-theme="a" data-position="left" data-role="panel"> any idea?

Comment: for that you can check options [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_panels_display)

Comment: hi turtle on click only these side panels are visible, but in my page they should be visible always and the page content should not be pushed both should fit according to the screen width

Comment: it seems you are looking for something like [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Sticky-Sidebar-Navigation-Menu-with-jQuery-Vertical-Navigation.html)

Comment: you have given example for sticky sidebar, but cant we make the panel like that?

Comment: I dont think so, because in your case I think you need the content always visible ( like a side menu ) and thats not a panel. In [JQM demo site](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/) they have also used a list view.

Answer (score -1):

Try **dismissible** option, default value is **true**.

> Sets whether the panel can be closed by clicking outside onto the
>   page. Also available via the data-dismissible attribute on the link
>   that opens the panel.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, any reason to downvote correct answer or just feeling jealous that our reputation may increase :p